Are these two codes the same?
There is an $ ((11,2,5)) $ CWS code given in table B2 at the end of
https://kth.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:894450/FULLTEXT01.pdf
I know that some CWS codes are equivalent to stabilizer codes, but also some are not.
Is this code the same as the famous $ [[11,1,5]] $ stabilizer code (see for example stabilizer generators given here http://www.codetables.de/QECC.php?q=4&n=11&k=1 or table 8.5 of https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9705052)?
I would not be surprised if they were the same since they are both distance 5 encodings of a single logical qubit into 11 physical qubits. But also I wouldn't be surprised if they were different since $ 11 $ is a big number and I don't think all 11 qubit stabilizer codes are known, let alone all CWS.
